# How does Xbox Live Gamertag recovery affect my achievements?

Tags: achievements, xbox-network

My Xbox 360 broke one day while I was not connected to Xbox Live. I recovered my Gamertag on my friend's Xbox 360 while connected to Xbox Live. I then earned a couple of achievements on his Xbox 360 while online.

Later on, I got a new Xbox 360 and started earning other achievements at home (note: still not connected to Xbox Live at this point). If I signed into Xbox Live and tried to recover my Gamertag back on my Xbox 360, would I still have the achievements I earned on my friend's Xbox 360 in addition to the ones that I just earned on my new offline Xbox 360 account?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the account you're using on your new Xbox is just a local GamerTag - it has never connected to Xbox Live.

If that is the case, when you recover your previous GamerTag, it will be a separate account from the new one you created. It should have any achievements that you've earned previously on that account, including those on your friend's Xbox (since it was online at the time).

After recovering your old account you'll still have the new one, but it will be a separate account with its own achievements.

Answer (score 1):

You can recover your old account and **it'll have the achievements synched at your friend's house**.

However, **you cannot merge two accounts** and won't be able to combine the achievements between your local and old accounts.